# ParserError: year 0 is out of range: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my python code is this.

```
y= data.iloc[:,1:-1]
train_data= pd.DataFrame()
train_data['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])
train_data['y']=y
train_data.head()
```

Error

```
ValueError: year 0 is out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()

ParserError: year 0 is out of range: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

TypeError: invalid string coercion to datetime

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: year 0 is out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ParserError: year 0 is out of range: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Comment: So did you debug? What is the value of `data["Date"]` at the moment of the error?

Comment: The exception seems self-explanatory.

Comment: yes, I have debugged it but still can't get it. at the error, the value was zero.

Comment: error may suggest that you have string `"0"` and it doesn't know how to parse it. It may not know if it is year, month, day, hours, minutes or seconds. You may have to write own function to parse it as value which you want (year, month, day, hours, minutes or seconds). But first you could display `data["Date"]` to see what you really have in this column.